# Commandline msbuild builds cause the Visual Studio 2012 IDE to hang

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

Command line invocations of msbuild.exe seems to cause vs2012 to become temporarily unresponsive.

msbuild.exe /p:Configuration=Debug /p:platform=x86 Solution.sln

Solution.sln is open in VS

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you might want to show us how your currently calling msbuild?

Comment: Do I suppose correctly you can build sln from Visual Studio without hang? If so, if I were you I try to specify target do build.
Try: **msbuild.exe /p:Configuration=Debug;Platform=x86 /t:Rebuild Solution.sln**